# how to interpret the word "all"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If I say "How to make 'all' cakes?", does it mean I'm asking for an instruction for making all cakes together or an instruction that is applied to every cake?

I want to figure out whether the "ALL" refers to quantity or something else?

Comment: I've altered your punctuation to express what I _think_ you are trying to say. I hope I'm right.

Comment: I'd say the latter, i.e. instructions that apply to every cake.

Comment: "How to make all cakes?" isn't a valid question. You'd have to ask "How do I make all cakes?" or "How are all cakes made?" or something else with a finite verb.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you want to make every type of cake (not necessarily immediately!). If you mean you want to make all cakes to be served at a particular party (for example), you need to say "all the cakes".